# Multiprocessing my Loop / Iteration ( Try...Except)

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

Im converting one chemical notation to another type. My list has like over 6k different names to convert and it takes so long. How can I use multiprocessing? I tried to implement myself, but im a noob. Other code optimisations are welcome too!

I tried to implement multiprocessing myself, but im a noob.

```
def resolve(str_input, representation):
    import cirpy
    return cirpy.resolve(str_input, representation)

compound_list = []
smiles_list = []

for index, row in df_Verteilung.iterrows():

    try:
        actual_smiles = resolve(row['Compound'], 'smiles')

    except:
        actual_smiles = 'Error'

    print('\r', row['Compound'], actual_smiles, end='')

    compound_list.append(row['Compound'])
    smiles_list.append(actual_smiles)

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Compound' : compound_list, 'SmilesCode' : smiles_list})
df_new.to_csv(index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pool from multiprocessing:

```py
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    def resolve(str_input, representation):
        try:
            import cirpy
            res =  cirpy.resolve(str_input, representation)
        except:
            res = "Error"

        print('\r', str_input, res, end='')
        return (str_input, res)

    n = 5

    with Pool(processes=n) as pool:
        compounds_smiles_list = pool.starmap(resolve, [(row['Compound'], 'smiles') for index, row in df_Verteilung.iterrows()])

    compound_list = [elem[0] for elem in compounds_smiles_list]
    smiles_list = [elem[1] for elem in compounds_smiles_list]

    df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Compound' : compound_list, 'SmilesCode' : smiles_list})
    df_new.to_csv(index=False)
```

Using the variable `n` you control the size of the Pool. Alternatively, you can leave the Pool constructor empty and an optimized number of workers will be chosen according to your system.

Some explanations:

[Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

[starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)

Comment: @Mr.Chang did it acheive an improvement in running time?

Comment: before it was like 1h now its just 10 min! thanks a lot!